# "No module named socket" "unresolved reference"

Tags: python, sockets

I am getting the errors in my code "No module named socket", "Unresolved reference 'input'", and "Unresolved reference 'print'". My code was working for me the other day. Why are these errors now showing up?

```
import socket


# Function to run the client and send messages to the server
def run_client():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000
    # Creating a TCP socket for the client
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Connecting to the server at the specified IP and port
    client_socket.connect((host, port))

    while True:
        # Reading input message from the user
        message = input("Enter message (enter 'end' to terminate): ")
        # Sending the message to the server
        client_socket.send(message.encode())

        # Receiving the response from the server
        response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        # Checking if the received message is "dne"
        if response == "dne":
            print(response)
            break
        else:
            # Printing the received message
            print("Received response:", response)

    # Closing the client socket
    print("Closing client socket")
    client_socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_client()
```

Comment: Did you call one of your files `socket.py`?

Comment: "Unresolved reference"? Do you have more context for where these errors show up? I don't see how these would be runtime errors.

Comment: @roganjosh no, I only have client.py and server.py

Comment: How about a much simpler script - `import socket` followed by `print(socket)`. That should hit both types of problems. Then, post the entire error message. And the environment where you are running. It seems python can't find modules in its own standard library. That can happen in a virtual environment which has restricted module access. It could happen in an IDE where the python environment is corrupted somehow.

Comment: Perhaps try to install a new python environment or update your existing one, and then run your code using this new environment.